# How to Enable Timestamp Option in IP Header

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, udp, ip

I am designing an application layer protocol on top of UDP. One of  requirements is that the receiving side should keep only the most up to date datagram.

Therefore, if datagram A was sent and then datagram B was sent, but datagram B was received first, datagram A should be discarded by the application when received.

One way to implement this is a counter stored in the data part of the UDP packet. The counter is incremented each time a datagram is sent.

I also noticed that IP options contain a timestamp option which looks suitable for this task.

My questions are (in the context of BSD-like sockets):

1. How do I enable this option on the sending side?
2. How do I read this field on the receiving side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set IP options using setsockopt() using option level IPPROTO_IP and specifying the name of the option. See Unix/Linux IP documentation, for example see [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/ip.7.html). Reading IP header options generally requires using a RAW socket which in turn usually requires root permissions. It's not advisable to (try to) use IP options because it may not always be supported since it's very rarely used (either at the origination system or at systems it passes).